How to sort an ArrayList of Objects by their ArrayList<Integer> values?
Suppose object has ArrayList<Integer> and an ArrayList of those objects needed to be sorted by their ArrayList<Integer> values so that, first index of the Integer ArrayList takes most priority, if both object's lists have the same first index then second index is compared ect. How would that be done?
For example, Imagine a OlympicWinner class that contains the name of the olympic winner and the medals they have won
public Class OlympicWinner {

//contains medals in order: [gold, silver, bronze]
private ArrayList<Integer> medals
private String name;

OlympicWinner (String name, int goldMedals, int silverMedals, int bronzeMedals) {
this.name = name;
this.medals = new ArrayList<Integer>;
this.medals.add(goldMedals);
this.medals.add(silverMedals);
this.medals.add(bronzeMedals);
}

public String getName() {return this.name;}

public ArrayList<Integer> getMedals() {return this.medals;}
}

Now if there was a list of ArrayList<OlympicWinner> olympicWinners and that list needed to be sorted by ArrayList<Integer> medals so that the first in the list would be the OlympicWinner, that has the most golds and if two had same amount of golds the one with most silver medals would be first and if both had the same amount of silver medals then the one with more bronze medals would be first. How would it be implemented?
I could think of this way:
Collections.sort(olympicWinners, new Comparator<OlympicWinner> () {
    @Override
    public int compare(OlympicWinner a, OlympicWinner b) {
        //comparison ...

        //ridiculous if comparison
        if(a.getMedals().get(0) > b.getMedals().get(0)) {
            return 1;
        } else if (a.getMedals().get(0) < b.getMedals().get(0)) {
            return -1;
        } else { //both have equal amount of gold medals, then compares silvers
            if(a.getMedals().get(1) > b.getMedals().get(1)) {
                return 1;
            } else if (a.getMedals().get(1) < b.getMedals().get(1)) {
                return -1;
            } else {} // and so on
        }

    } // comparison ends here    
});

but I'm not sure how to implement the compare method for ArrayList<Integer> nor do I know if this sorting method Collections.sort() as a whole is the best way to do it. The ridiculos if method not only looks bad, but isn't applicable to the abstract version of this, in which the ArrayList<Integer> could have length of n. (where n is any whole number)

BTW a List is not the best for storing three numbers (it is more indicated for a variable number of elements). Maybe better use a record or even a class (record Medals(int gold, int silver, int bronze) {}) (Java is an object-oriented language, don't be afraid of creatig new objects)

One could treat the medal list as a base N number where N is the maximum possible value for each thing (medal).  For example, assuming 10 (convenient) maximum medals per type then someone who has 2 golds, 3 silvers and 1 bronze evaluates to 231.  Then a single value can be computed and used in the comparator.  You wouldn't need a list at all but maintain the value as medals are added.  Again base 10 was used for clarity but N could be any number.  Also, given a number one could easily extract the individual "thing" counts.

You have the right idea with implementing a Comparator, but there's a couple of things that could (should?) be improved here.
First, there's no need to manually compare each set of corresponding medals. You can use Integer.compare and let it do the heavy lifting for you.
Second, as you noted, there's a lot of boilerplate code here, where you have the same logic for gold, silver and then bronze medals, and had there been more types of medals, it would just have been worse - as you noted already. The way to handle that is with a loop - you can iterate over the medal types, and once you hit a pair of medals with different numbers, return that comparison. If you don't, both OlympicWinners are equivalent:
Comparator<OlympicWinner> medalsComparator = new Comparator<OlympicWinner>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(OlympicWinner o1, OlympicWinner o2) {
        // Don't assume how many medals an OlypicWinner has, 
        // but assume o1 and o2 have the same length of the medals member
        List<Integer> m1 = o1.getMedals();
        List<Integer> m2 = o2.getMedals();
        for (int i = 0; i < m1.size(); ++i) {
            int res = Integer.compare(m1.get(i), m2.get(i));
            if (res != 0) {
                // Negate the comparison so you get a descending order
                return -1 * res;
            }
        }

        // No pair of corresponding medals has a different count,
        // so o1 and o2 must be equivalent
        return 0;
    }

As noted in the comment, this comparator doesn't assume that there are only three types of medals, but does assume that both OlympicWinners have the same number of types (i.e., same size of the medals list). If this assumption isn't always true the code should be modified to accommodate it, but for the sake of keeping the example simple, I took that assumption.

This code breaks contract and thus causes problems. It only works if each sublist has identical amounts of integers in it. [1,2,3] is equal to both [1,2,3,4] and [1,2,3,5], but [1,2,3,4] and [1,2,3,5] are not equal to each other, breaking the rule: if (a == b && b == c) assert a == c;

@rzwitserloot I literally noted that assumption. And if you look at the question's details, that's a more than reasonable assumption - both OlympicWInners presumably compete in the same competition(s), so they'd have access to the same medal types.

@rzwitserloot, there cannot be four medals (there are only three) and the list cannot contain two values (or one) as it would be impossible to discriminate which award they correspond to.

@MarcePuente your comparator is still broken; it now applies only specifically to medal tables but the code doesn't yell that out other than via its identifiers. The code in question should thus be thoroughly expanded, with checks to ensure the list is always precisely 3 large, and more generally List<Integer> now feels like the wrong data type to convey this information.

I'm a bit confused why a thoroughly worse answer is getting the upvotes. This is far less universally applicable, does not include example code that can be readily pasted, and does not show general principles such as using Comparator.comparing to expand the concept of 'how do I construct code that does sorting based on the basics' as much either.

@rzwitserloot, I totally agree, the medal list should be represented with an int[ 3 ], but in this particular case, the fact of arriving at a list with two Item's, would be placing the problem in another part of the code, not in this sorting.

Let's break this question down into 2 separate parts:

Find a way to sort a list of objects based on providing some code that can derive a property for any object and we want to sort on the derived property.
Sort a list of List<Integer> objects in the way you described: First integer wins; look at second only if first are equal, and so on.

Sort a list of list-of-integers
List<List<Integer>> example = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
example.add(List.of(2, 1, 1, 1, 1));
example.add(List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 6));
example.add(List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));

example.sort((a, b) -> {
  for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(a.size(), b.size()); i++) {
    int c = a.get(i).compareTo(b.get(i));
    if (c != 0) return c;
  }
  // We ran out of elements; the larger list thus wins
  return Integer.compare(a.size(), b.size());
});

for (var list : example) System.out.println(list);

This prints:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
[2, 1, 1, 1, 1]


Note, (a, b) -> c is a shorter way to do what you did: We provide an implementation of Comparator here, but we ditch all the boilerplate and just write only the compare(T a, T b) function. This is called 'lambda syntax' and you can search the web for java lambda syntax if you want to know more.

So that's working!
Now that we can do that, we can trivially solve for 1:
Sort on a derived property
class Foo {
  List<Integer> ints;

  Foo(int... args) {
    this.ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int arg : args) this.ints.add(arg);
  }

  @Override public String toString() {
    return ints.toString();
  }
}

List<Foo> example = new ArrayList<>();
example.add(new Foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 6));
example.add(new Foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
example.add(new Foo(2, 1, 1, 1, 1));

Comparator<List<Integer>> intListComparator = (a, b) -> {
  for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(a.size(), b.size()); i++) {
    int c = a.get(i).compareTo(b.get(i));
    if (c != 0) return c;
  }
  // We ran out of elements; the larger list thus wins
  return Integer.compare(a.size(), b.size());
};

example.sort(Comparator.comparing(f -> f.ints, intListComparator));

for (var f : example) System.out.println(f);


The comparator in this second snippet is copy-pasted from part 1.
Comparator.comparing(x, y) is the magic here. x is a function that derives a property. Here, given an f, it derives the list of integers. The y is a comparator that can decide given any 2 derived properties (here, given 2 lists of integers), which one is 'higher' / if they are order-wise the same by returning positive, negative, or 0.


@Mureinik used Collections.sort(...) and compare method, you are used .sort on the object ArrayList and Comparator.comparing(...). Whats the difference? Is one faster than the other?

In the case that one ArrayList<Integer> is bigger than the other, the code does not specify which one is 'higher' than the other. I.e. [1,2,3] [1,2] neither would be deterministically put higher or lower.

There is no difference; these are different ways to run the same code. Java is trying to move away from 'utility classes' and move towards just calling methods on objects like proper OOP. Collections.sort is in that sense obsolete and list.sort is superior. Not for performance reasons; for code cleanliness ones.

If you have a comparator that is not consistent, 'weird things' can happen. Hence why they should just be consistent. I decided to pick an arbitrary way to do so ('shorter list is lower'); if you don't care, great - then any choice is good enough. But a choice is required.

There is a trick you can use to make this a lot easier:  IntBuffer already does the comparison you want.
So you can store your medal counts in an IntBuffer instead:
public class OlympicWinner {

    //contains medals in order: [gold, silver, bronze]
    private IntBuffer medals;
    private String name;

    OlympicWinner (String name, int goldMedals, int silverMedals, int bronzeMedals) {
        this.name = name;
        this.medals = IntBuffer.allocate(3);
        this.medals.put(goldMedals);
        this.medals.put(silverMedals);
        this.medals.put(bronzeMedals);
        this.medals.rewind();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public IntBuffer getMedalsAsBuffer() {
        return this.medals.asReadOnlyBuffer();
    }

    // In case any other code still relies on this method...
    public ArrayList<Integer> getMedals() {
        IntBuffer buffer = getMedalsAsBuffer();
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(buffer.remaining());
        while (buffer.hasRemaining()) {
            list.add(buffer.get());
        }
        return list;
    }
}

Now your sorting is quite easy:
Collections.sort(olympicWinners,
    Comparator.comparing(OlympicWinner::getMedalsAsBuffer));


For the lazy ones like me who prefer to use built-in functions instead of coding themselves, you can also take a small diversions and use Arrays.compare. However, this requires that you convert the list into an array. From the docs for Arrays.compare:

Compares two int arrays lexicographically.
If the two arrays share a common prefix then the lexicographic comparison is the result of comparing two elements, as if by Integer.compare(int, int), at an index within the respective arrays that is the prefix length. Otherwise, one array is a proper prefix of the other and, lexicographic comparison is the result of comparing the two array lengths. (See mismatch(int[], int[]) for the definition of a common and proper prefix.)
A null array reference is considered lexicographically less than a non-null array reference. Two null array references are considered equal.

So the comparator for the given example with a sample list could look like:
List<OlympicWinner> olympicWinnerList = new ArrayList<>();
olympicWinnerList.add(new OlympicWinner("Bob", 1,2,0));
olympicWinnerList.add(new OlympicWinner("Joe", 3,2,4));
olympicWinnerList.add(new OlympicWinner("Tom", 3,2,2));
olympicWinnerList.add(new OlympicWinner("Rob", 3,1,3));

Comparator<OlympicWinner> byMedals = (x,y) -> Arrays.compare(
        x.getMedals().stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray(),
        y.getMedals().stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray());

olympicWinnerList.sort(byMedals.reversed());


The Answer by rzwitserloot is correct and worthy, addressing the Question directly. I will pick up on the Comment about a List being a poor choice for a known set of attributes.
List
A collection is meant for an unknown or variable number of items. For example, a set of any number of Employee objects assigned to a Project object.
In the case of Olympic medals, we know for certain there are exactly three categories: Gold, Silver, Bronze. So using a Collection like Set or List is not the best fit.
record
In the case of a known set of attributes, define a class. If the main purpose of this class is to transparently communicate shallowly-immutable data, then make it a record.
public record MedalCount ( int gold , int silver , int bronze ) {}

Then we can define our Olympic athlete as a record containing a MedalCount record.
public record OlympicWinner ( String name , MedalCount medalCount ) { }

Of course in this example, we could have just made gold, silver, and bronze members fields on OlympicWinner, and dispense with the MedalCount record. But I presume the Question is really about something more complicated than this contrived example. So, go with this.
Then we can easily define a Comparator to sort by cascading of Gold, then Silver, then Bronze, per your specification.
Comparator < OlympicWinner > comparatorCascadingCount =
        Comparator
                .comparingInt( ( OlympicWinner olympicWinner ) -> olympicWinner.medalCount( ).gold( ) )
                .thenComparingInt( ( OlympicWinner olympicWinner ) -> olympicWinner.medalCount( ).silver( ) )
                .thenComparingInt( ( OlympicWinner olympicWinner ) -> olympicWinner.medalCount( ).bronze( ) )
                .reversed( );

By the way, some people would argue that your cascading count is less fair than a count of points where Gold is worth 3 points, Silver 2, and Bronze 1. Athletes with many Silver and Bronze are then ranked higher. For an example, notice how Carl Lewis and Isabell Werth switch places in the sample output far below.
Here is the Comparator by points.
Comparator < OlympicWinner > comparatorPoints =
        Comparator
                .comparingInt( ( OlympicWinner olympicWinner ) ->
                        ( olympicWinner.medalCount( ).gold( ) * 3 )
                                + ( olympicWinner.medalCount( ).bronze( ) * 2 )
                                + olympicWinner.medalCount( ).silver( )
                )
                .reversed( );

Full example code:
package work.basil.example.counting;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        App app = new App( );
        app.demo( );
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        // Data after the 2024 Summer Olympics.
        List < OlympicWinner > winners =
                List.of(
                        new OlympicWinner( "Tom Daley" , new MedalCount( 1 , 1 , 3 ) ) ,
                        new OlympicWinner( "Michael Phelps" , new MedalCount( 23 , 3 , 2 ) ) ,
                        new OlympicWinner( "Paavo Nurmi" , new MedalCount( 9 , 3 , 0 ) ) ,
                        new OlympicWinner( "Carl Lewis" , new MedalCount( 9 , 1 , 0 ) ) ,
                        new OlympicWinner( "Mark Spitz" , new MedalCount( 9 , 1 , 1 ) ) ,
                        new OlympicWinner( "Yusuf Dikeç" , new MedalCount( 0 , 1 , 0 ) ) ,
                        new OlympicWinner( "Larisa Latynina" , new MedalCount( 9 , 5 , 4 ) ) ,
                        new OlympicWinner( "Isabell Werth" , new MedalCount( 8 , 6 , 0 ) )
                );

        List < OlympicWinner > winnersSortedByCascadingCount = new ArrayList <>( winners );
        Comparator < OlympicWinner > comparatorCascadingCount =
                Comparator
                        .comparingInt( ( OlympicWinner olympicWinner ) -> olympicWinner.medalCount( ).gold( ) )
                        .thenComparingInt( ( OlympicWinner olympicWinner ) -> olympicWinner.medalCount( ).silver( ) )
                        .thenComparingInt( ( OlympicWinner olympicWinner ) -> olympicWinner.medalCount( ).bronze( ) )
                        .reversed( );
        winnersSortedByCascadingCount.sort( comparatorCascadingCount );

        List < OlympicWinner > winnersSortedByPoints = new ArrayList <>( winners );
        Comparator < OlympicWinner > comparatorPoints =
                Comparator
                        .comparingInt( ( OlympicWinner olympicWinner ) ->
                                ( olympicWinner.medalCount( ).gold( ) * 3 )
                                        + ( olympicWinner.medalCount( ).bronze( ) * 2 )
                                        + olympicWinner.medalCount( ).silver( )
                        )
                        .reversed( );
        winnersSortedByPoints.sort( comparatorPoints );

        System.out.println( "---------|  Sorted by Cascading Count |------------ " );
        winnersSortedByCascadingCount.forEach( System.out :: println );
        System.out.println( "\n" );

        System.out.println( "---------|  Sorted by Points |------------ " );
        winnersSortedByPoints.forEach( System.out :: println );
        System.out.println( "\n" );
    }
}

When run, we see Carl Lewis and Isabell Werth switch places.
---------|  Sorted by Cascading Count |------------ 
OlympicWinner[name=Michael Phelps, medalCount=MedalCount[gold=23, silver=3, bronze=2]]
OlympicWinner[name=Larisa Latynina, medalCount=MedalCount[gold=9, silver=5, bronze=4]]
OlympicWinner[name=Paavo Nurmi, medalCount=MedalCount[gold=9, silver=3, bronze=0]]
OlympicWinner[name=Mark Spitz, medalCount=MedalCount[gold=9, silver=1, bronze=1]]
OlympicWinner[name=Carl Lewis, medalCount=MedalCount[gold=9, silver=1, bronze=0]]
OlympicWinner[name=Isabell Werth, medalCount=MedalCount[gold=8, silver=6, bronze=0]]
OlympicWinner[name=Tom Daley, medalCount=MedalCount[gold=1, silver=1, bronze=3]]
OlympicWinner[name=Yusuf Dikeç, medalCount=MedalCount[gold=0, silver=1, bronze=0]]


---------|  Sorted by Points |------------ 
OlympicWinner[name=Michael Phelps, medalCount=MedalCount[gold=23, silver=3, bronze=2]]
OlympicWinner[name=Larisa Latynina, medalCount=MedalCount[gold=9, silver=5, bronze=4]]
OlympicWinner[name=Paavo Nurmi, medalCount=MedalCount[gold=9, silver=3, bronze=0]]
OlympicWinner[name=Mark Spitz, medalCount=MedalCount[gold=9, silver=1, bronze=1]]
OlympicWinner[name=Isabell Werth, medalCount=MedalCount[gold=8, silver=6, bronze=0]]
OlympicWinner[name=Carl Lewis, medalCount=MedalCount[gold=9, silver=1, bronze=0]]
OlympicWinner[name=Tom Daley, medalCount=MedalCount[gold=1, silver=1, bronze=3]]
OlympicWinner[name=Yusuf Dikeç, medalCount=MedalCount[gold=0, silver=1, bronze=0]]

